# I can't log into my Pokémon Trainer Club account from the Pokémon Global Link website

Tags: pokemon-sun-moon, pokemon-global-link

I'm having problems using game sync. I created a Pokemon Trainer Club account. When I go to the Pokemon Global Link website, I can't log in, it just reloads. I'm trying to do this on my ipad.

Comment: Probably the site is just busy due to high traffic, try again later.

Comment: Really, there's no ETA, or acknowledgement of this issue from Nintendo / The Pokemon Company.

Comment: have you tried on another device? or even a full blooded computer instead of a tablet or phone?

Answer (score 1):

According to another user, the website is down due to very high traffic. There's no ETA or acknowledgement from Nintendo/The Pokémon Company about this issue.

Comment: Unfotunately, i don't think that is the problem. It has been doing this for quite some time.